# How to add probabilities to model.predict output?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, text-classification

I've built a functioning classification model following [this tutorial](https://kavita-ganesan.com/news-classifier-with-logistic-regression-in-python/#Saving-Logistic-Regression-Model).

The tutorial only outputs the predicted category names. I want it to output the category name and its probability and I only want to output categories above a certain probability. For example, I only want categories over .5

This is the function used to access the model:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
category_model_path="categorymodel.pkl"
category_transformer_path="categorytransformer.pkl"
sentiment_model_path="sentimentmodel.pkl"
sentiment_transformer_path="sentimenttransformer.pkl"

def get_top_k_predictions(model,X_test,k):
    
    # get probabilities instead of predicted labels, since we want to collect top 3
    np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
    probs = model.predict_proba(X_test)

    # GET TOP K PREDICTIONS BY PROB - note these are just index
    best_n = np.argsort(probs, axis=1)[:,-k:]
    
    # GET CATEGORY OF PREDICTIONS
    preds=[[model.classes_[predicted_cat] for predicted_cat in prediction] for prediction in best_n]
    
    preds=[ item[::-1] for item in preds]
    
    return preds

category_loaded_model = pickle.load(open(category_model_path, 'rb'))
category_loaded_transformer = pickle.load(open(category_transformer_path, 'rb'))

sentiment_loaded_model = pickle.load(open(sentiment_model_path, 'rb'))
sentiment_loaded_transformer = pickle.load(open(sentiment_transformer_path, 'rb'))
```

Then this code is used to call the function:

```
category_test_features=category_loaded_transformer.transform(["I absolutley loved the organization "])
get_top_k_predictions(category_loaded_model,category_test_features,2)
```

This is the current output:

```
[['Course Structure', 'Learning Materials']]
```

The probabilities are calculated in the function to the `probs` variable. I do not know how to only get the ones over .5 and add these to the `preds` output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `best_n` array contains the indices to the array of probabilities `probs`. You can use it in the same way as you do for getting the labels. You can get label-probability tuples like this:

```py
preds = [
    [(model.classes_[predicted_cat], distribution[predicted_cat])
     for predicted_cat in prediction]
    for distribution, prediction in zip(probs, best_n)]
```

If you do not want to return the probabilities and only want to filter them, you can do something like:

```py
preds=[
    [model.classes_[predicted_cat]
     for predicted_cat in prediction if distribution[predicted_cat] > 0.5]
    for distribution, prediction in zip(probs, best_n)]
```

Comment: Any idea how to sort the array alphabetically by the label name?